# Progress Dialog in Android

Tags: android

can i keep progress dialog anywhere in activity??
if possible then how can i do it???

Answer (score 2):

A Progress Dialog will appear above your activity but you can use the ProgressBar widget to show the progress indicator somewhere in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
// Request progress bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

to show an undeterminate progress spinner in the title bar.